# What is "unusual childbirth pain"?

Tags: pregnancy-birth

The Talmud [Yevamot 65b, Ketubot 60a] allows a woman to sterilize herself if she suffers unusual childbirth pain.

What is "unusual childbirth pain"?  Women testify to the fact that there is no worse pain than childbirth pain.

Comment: I don't understand what you are expecting in an answer. What units of pain would someone measure this in?

Comment: I don't know.  I am asking what the Talmud has in mind.  Rulings cannot be left vague.

Comment: Seemingly it meant "unusual" pain and not what most people have.

Comment: So all a woman has to do is say that she thinks childbirth would give her unusual pain, and then she is allowed to sterilize herself? If not, how do you apply the leniency?

Comment: That doesn't follow. Perhaps a doctor has to approve it? Is that what you want to ask about?

Comment: All a doctor could say is something like:. She is unusually tight and so would experience unusual pain. But then he would recommend a Caesarian, not sterilization. If he thinks that would put her life in danger, then it's pikuach nefesh, a totally different category.

Comment: Presumably it would be pain that when described to a doctor/midwife, sounds different than what most women describe.